# Class to specific divs shall I add some id somewhere

Tags: html, css

the following code applies gray box to all `<divs>` I would like to apply the class to specific `divs` shall I add some id somewhere?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 320px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Calculate the total width:</h2>

<img src="klematis4_big.jpg" width="350" height="263" alt="Klematis">
<div>The picture above is 350px wide. The total width of this element is also 350px.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: use `div.someClass` instead of just `div` in your css. Then in your markup add `class="someClass"` where you want your styles to apply.

Comment: An ID can only be used on a single element. If you want to apply the same CSS to multiple elements, use a class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ID (`#idname`), or better yet, a reusable class (`.classname`) would be appropriate for styling this element.

```css
.caption {
  width: 320px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Calculate the total width:</h2>

<img src="http://placehold.it/350x263" width="350" height="263" alt="Klematis">
<div class="caption">The picture above is 350px wide. The total width of this element is also 350px.</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            greyBox {
                width: 320px;
                padding: 10px;
                border: 5px solid gray;
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>Calculate the total width:</h2>

    <img src="klematis4_big.jpg" width="350" height="263" alt="Klematis">
    <div class = "greyBox" >The picture above is 350px wide. The total width of this element is also 350px.</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

**CSS**

```
.newStyle {
    width: 320px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>Calculate the total width:</h2>

<img src="klematis4_big.jpg" width="350" height="263" alt="Klematis">
<div id="dvText">The picture above is 350px wide. The total width of this element is also 350px.</div>
```

**JAVA SCRIPT**

```
function addClass(el, className) {
  var classes = el.className.match(/\S+/g) || [];  

  if (!hasClass(el, className)) {
    classes.push(className);
  }
  el.className = classes.join(' ');
}

function hasClass(el, className) {
  var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + className + '(\\s+|$)');
  return re.test(el.className);
}

addClass(document.getElementById('dvText'), 'newStyle')
```